# How to assign value from varibles to the enties of list

Tags: python, list

I have the following python code:

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = 1

command = ['entry1', 'entry2=', 'entry3=', 'entry4=']
```

I would like to assign the values of varibles `a, b,c` to `entry2, entry3, entry4` respectively. So, `command[1]`  needs to return `entr2=2`,  `command[2]` `entry3=3`, `command[3]`  `entry4=1` respectively.

Could someone please assist me on how to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use string formatting:

```
command = ['entry1', f'entry2={a}', f'entry3={b}', f'entry4={c}']
```